# Downloaded P 12 file from Google to my computer and dont remember password

Tags: security

When I try to upload to a software it asks for a password that is protecting personal information. I dont recall this PW. How can I change the password so I can upload my p 12 file

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Sorry. You have to decrypt the file, for which you need the password. Can you go back to the source and ask for a new one?